# Django Redirect back two pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a decorator protecting certain parts of my site.

```
def admin_only(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Group.objects.get(name='admin') in request.user.groups.all():
            return redirect('main:unauthorized')
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _view
```

So if the user is not in the admin group, they are redirected to a view that renders an 'unauthorized blah blah blah template'.

What I want to do is redirect the user back to where they were when they tried to access the forbidden page. I'll then use something like

```
if not Group.objects.get(name='admin') in request.user.groups.all():
            messages.error("Unauthorized blah blah blah"
            **redirect to where they were or home incase they used direct link**
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` is the link the user was at when they tried to access the forbidden view

```
  def admin_only(view):
        @wraps(view)
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not Group.objects.get(name='admin') in request.user.groups.all():
                messages.error(request, "Access Denied")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _view
```

You can follow the conversation on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/mmrrkw/redirect_back_two_pages/)